# Convert a shapefile to KML whilst retaining each polygon label in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert

I have a publicly available shapefile that shows tree species in all the National Resources Wales forests.  I have clipped the file to the single forest of interest with the species as Label.  This displays exactly as I wanted in QGIS but when exported as KML it only shows polygons, no labels.  I tried the link suggested but it didn't work with my starting file.    I also tried exporting as SQLite but still had polygons, no labels.  It is possible that the clipping has corrupted the file?  It is labelled as scratch layer, if I 'Make permanent' polygons and labels disappear.  I have tried exporting original (unclipped) as KML with same results so it is not the clipping that causes the problem.  I have retried saving in different formats, SQL, Shapefile but noticed that when"Save as layer" is ticked the layer initially has no labels but if I set label to prispecies or unset/reset the labels then appear.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work in my case. Still polygons, no labels.

Comment: Are you trying to get the labels shown in Google Earth, or are you re-adding the KML to QGIS and want to see the labels in QGIS?

Comment: I can see labels in QGIS but not in GEP when exported as kml.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a field named 'Name' and put your labels under that field. Then, export the data as KML.

Comment: Should I add 'Name' to Shapefile?  If so how?

Comment: Yes. Easiest way is probably to use the field calculator to create a new string field equal to the value of the field you want to use as the label.

Comment: Field calculator is beyond my experience,could you give some pointers please.

Answer (score 0):

Not as I wanted but close, the polygons are not labelled when loaded into GEP as they are in QGIS but give a polygon a left click and the attributes pop up in a dialogue box.  Any unwanted fields were deleted in Properties-Fields to keep pop up compact and relevant to CRST users.